# Show price for each selected row in gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Want to show price of a selected in datagridview into a lablel. For now am using a loop to show the price but it only give me the first selected price only.

**Code to show price**

```
int selectedCellCount = dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

if (selectedCellCount > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedCellCount; i++)
    {

        int row = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex;
        label3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    }

}
```

[image: Only first row is showing price]

Also how can i calculate total price for entered  quantity

Comment: The problem is, each time, you are rewriting the text of your label inside the `for` loop.

Comment: You overwrite the label text in each iteration of your loop.

Comment: @S.Akbari so i need to remove the label statement from the loop and put it outside?

Comment: @Liam yes, it is windows forms application

Comment: Okay. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

I think that I got your point from your comment on one of the answer. You want that whenever you select row, price of the selected row show in label ? Right.

For this you can use DataGridView Event named SelectionChanged(), so whenever your selection changed, this event triggers and change your label.

Assuming your gridview allows only one selection.

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    label.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: For some reason its showing error in row.Cells[3].Value; it is showing " cannot implicitly convert type object to string

Comment: Try this one
row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

Comment: Nothing changed it is the same

Comment: Did you convert it into string ?

Comment: okay now when i run the winform code, i get this error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.

Comment: Did you select an empty cell ? This error raised when an empty cell is selected.

Comment: No, i can't even open the form to select anything. it will show me the error when i click on the button to check the form

Comment: Now I think this error that you just mentioned is because of some different issue.

Comment: Still man im getting the same error when i try to open gridview form System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' ----- Do u think the error is from the event selectchanged

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.

Comment: Did you create event from form properties event tab or copy paste above code ?

Comment: Did you fix this ?

Comment: I created the even from the properties by selected gridview and choose selectchanged event, still the same error

Comment: How can i send it bro? it is to long!

Comment: Thanks man. ur answer was close to ma issue i found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<int> indexes = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => Select(x => x.Index).ToList();
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
{
    // here the label text will be the last row price because you overwrite each time
    label3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    sum += int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

}
MessageBox.Show("Sum of selected rows = " + sum.ToString());
```

Comment: I think there's no question about summarize but calculate = price * qty... if there's `MultiSelect=False`, current row can get by `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value`, fastest and easiest way to get value.

Comment: @Ali tell us more please what represents the quantity?

Comment: Okay for example i have a row of a specific item, when i select the row it will show me the price of the item in a label. when u put the number of quantity u want of the item in the textbox it will calculate, price of item * quantity to get the total price

Comment: well, one advice, use `javascript` for that calculation... since You have not specifically tell us how calculation will be perform - while typing qty in textbox or click some of those two buttons... anyway, perform calculation by `JS` to avoid unnecessary `postback` ... and, where result will be showed? This begun to chatty, provide us `html` too, and explain more about questions I, and everybody else, asked.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the Answer. Thanks everybody**

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) // make sure user select at least 1 row 
        {
           label3.Text =  dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;
        }
```